# Error 1882 recovering Oracle dump File - Timezone region not found

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

sorry for my English.

I'm trying to restore an Oracle database through a dump I have the server that crashed .

The database was exported in oracle 10g .

When I start to import through the imp tool , it returns me the following error:

```
Import fails with following errors:
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1882 encountered
ORA-01882: timezone region not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_EXPORT_EXTENSION", line 810
ORA-06512: at line 1
IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file
```

I run the command:

```
imp file=2015-06-27_biblioteca.dmp log=my.log fromuser=BIBLIOTECA touser=BIBLIOTECA full=y
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `imp` tool is quite old, you should use Data Pump `impdp`, resp. `expdp` instead.

Comment: My backup was generated by the imp tool